# SQL use temporary tables in trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, hashtable

I have a trigger in MSSQL Server 2008R2 :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_HosFile_Delete] 
    ON [dbo].[hosfile] FOR DELETE 
AS 
    insert into #pys(pyGuid)
    SELECT EntryGuid AS pyGuid FROM er000 AS er

    insert into t2(C1) select pyGuid from #pys
```

After the trigger has executed the `t2` table is empty. Why is it empty?

If I execute the query above without a trigger the `t2` table is filled.

is there any problem with using a temporary table in a trigger?

Comment: Which database system? SQL is a language, implemented in various database systems. Any you've not shown us a trigger. Triggers are vastly different in different database systems.

Comment: You don't create the table `#pys` anywhere. It would need to have been created in a parent scope. Probably you are getting an error that the object doesn't exist.

Comment: Why use a temp table for this, instead of directly inserting? 

`INSERT INTO T2(C1) SELECT EntryGuid FROM er000`

Answer (score 7):

Damien's answer is correct: you can use temporary tables in triggers, but it is strongly recommended to define them there, since the trigger can fire in various contexts.

If you use temporary tables in triggers, check for temporary table existence as you do not control the context and it might be already there:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#pys') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #pys
```

Also, temporary tables can be created on the fly:

```
SELECT * INTO #tmp
FROM inserted
```

This is particularly useful when trigger contains dynamic SQL that needs to access inserted or deleted special tables which are not visible in the dynamic SQL scope.

Avoid using ##tmp (global temporary variables), as these are globally visible and can lead to trouble when multiple SPIDs are firing you trigger.

Answer (score 3):

There's no problem using temp tables, provided that they're in scope at the time the trigger fires.

Given that the trigger can fire at any time, on any connection, the only scope that makes sense is within the body of the trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_HosFile_Delete] 
    ON [dbo].[hosfile] FOR DELETE 
AS 
    CREATE TABLE #pys (pyGuid uniqueidentifier not null/*I'm guessing*/)

    insert into #pys(pyGuid)
    SELECT EntryGuid AS pyGuid FROM er000 AS er

    insert into t2(C1) select pyGuid from #pys
```

(To be honest, I'm not sure if you could access a temp table from an outer scope, and don't have an instance handy to test it. But, even if you can, it would make for a very brittle trigger)

Answer (score 0):

If you use ##pys  (notice the double # sign) it will be globally available after its creation. That might help in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SELECT INTO to create and populate the temporary table. There are some restrictions when using a temp table inside a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Just a as a quick supplement to this thread as it is not clear from other posts about the continuity of temporary tables between triggers and the initiating query:

It is possible to read (SELECT FROM) and update (INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE) session (#) temporary tables inside a trigger.

I find this particularly useful for passing data into a trigger that might be needed for it to complete.

For example I use it in a trigger that writes table and field level changes to an audit log file that goes along the lines of "User X change field Y from A to B". But to achieve this I need information about the database user (who is not the actual SQL Server user the service is running under, but a user in my "Users" table.)

The only way to pass this information to the trigger is by use of a #Table populated with the User credentials and other session information. Always test for the existence of the temporary table inside the trigger.

Before the trigger:

```
IF object_id(''tempdb..#UserCredentials'') IS NOT NULL');
    EXEC('DROP TABLE #UserCredentials')
CREATE TABLE #UserCredentials ([UserType] VARCHAR(20), [UserID] BIGINT, [Date] DATETIME)
 :
DELETE FROM #UserCredentials
INSERT INTO #UserCredentials ([UserType], [UserID], [Date]) 
    VALUES (@system_usertype, @system_userid, @system_date)

UPDATE MyTable...
```

Inside the trigger:

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#UserCredentials') IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @system_usertype = [UserType], @system_userid = [UserID], @system_date = [Date] FROM #UserCredentials
```